# Using a C++ variable in MSSQL query

Tags: c++, sql-server

First off, C++ is a new language to me although I have coded in a few others; so please forgive any ignorance of C++ on my part. I've worked out how to do database connections, and simple queries; however the thing that's throwing me completely is the use of variables in said queries.

I've got the following query that happily inserts data into my DB, but I can't for the life of me work out how to do the same query but inserting a variable instead of static text.

```
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, (SQLCHAR*)"insert into testtable (name) values ('testname');", SQL_NTS)) {
    show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
    goto FINISHED;
}
```

I've done quite a lot of reading around but nobody seems to give a clear, or even the same, answer. The only constant theme is that, for obvious reasons, I should be using a prepared statement. However even this method varies wildly in application from person to person.

Using VS2015 and SQL Server 2014.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all of the pointers, I've added the below code and it's now happily inserting variables!

```
char* newvar;
newvar = "preptest";
SQLCHAR newquery[100];
    sprintf((char*)newquery, "INSERT INTO testtable (name) VALUES ('%s');", newvar);
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, newquery, SQL_NTS)) {
    show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
}
```

If (lol, if; when) you see any other no-nos please feel free to point them out. A quick follow up question, if the variable needs to include an escape character, how do I go about ignoring it? Or do I just use RE to escape the escape char?

Comment: Not exactly a no-no like `goto' but a hard cast right in the middle of somewhere is ugly at best. I would at least wrap that in a minimal  conversion function. Thus if you once get problems with the SQLCHAR to (whatever) char_type conversion, you can intercept there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can't for the life of me work out how to do the same query but
> inserting a variable instead of static text.

A  plain [`std::sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) into a `char[MAX_STATEMENT_LENGTH]` sql-query buffer could do the job (although that can be refined according to your needs, of course).

Btw - a `goto`

```
    goto FINISHED;
```

is generally a no-no in C and C++. The very few occasions where they are unavoidable, or that much more efficient than staying with block-based execution control, just confirm that rule.

Idiomatic C++ would be `throw` ing and handling an exception in a [try/catch-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch)

Comment: So define the query using sprintf and then execute the query later? Or am I way off?

Comment: @dailygrind Well, 'later' may be in the next line of code thus let's better put it *you do it in two steps*.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I think I'm getting closer. Should I run it with SQLExecDirect?

Comment: **if** (and so it appears) you want to use `SQLExecDirect` instead of prepared statements then "yes". I would however dispute that `SQLExecDirect` is the icing on the MSSQL API cake.

Comment: Updated the question with the new code, thanks again! There is a quick follow-up though ^